# How do I access Core Data Attribute validation information from code?

Tags: core-data

I have a string attribute in a Core Data entity whose Max Length value is 40. I'd like to use this value in code and not have to re-type the value "40." Is this possible?

Comment: Obvious question, but needs to be asked nevertheless: are you certain it's the best solution to know this number in your core? Maybe calling `validateValue:forKey:error:` will work for you?

Comment: In this particular case, I don't want to know the value so that I can see if the value is invalid. I actually want to trim a string to this length so I can ensure it is valid.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain about this, but I think the part of CoreData you're trying to hook into is proprietary code. Since there aren't any answers, I advise you to write the same check into your code and register it as a validation method for KVC.

Comment: So, you're saying avoid duplication by not using the Max Length feature of Core Data (so the "40" will not appear there anymore), but instead make a constant for "40" in my code and use it from both a new validation method I hook up (which replaces the original Max Length feature) and also from the place I trim strings. That sounds reasonable. If you want to create an answer I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @K.Steff says in the comments above, you are better off validating in your code and not setting a max length in your core data model. To add on to that comment, I would also advise you to look at using a custom NSManagedObject subclass for this entity type, and within that subclass overriding the `validateValue:forKey:error:` or implementing a key-specific validation method for this property.

The value of this approach is that you can do things like "coerce" the validation by truncating strings at validation time. From the NSManagedObject documentation:

> This method is responsible for two things: coercing the value into an appropriate
> type for the object, and validating it according to the object’s rules.
>
> The default implementation provided by NSManagedObject consults the object’s entity
> description to coerce the value and to check for basic errors, such as a null value when
> that isn’t allowed and the length of strings when a field width is specified for the
> attribute. It then searches for a method of the form validate< Key >:error: and invokes it
> if it exists.
>
> You can implement methods of the form validate< Key >:error: to perform validation that is
> not possible using the constraints available in the property description. If it finds an
> unacceptable value, your validation method should return NO and in error an NSError object
> that describes the problem. For more details, see “Model Object Validation”. For
> inter-property validation (to check for combinations of values that are invalid), see
> validateForUpdate: and related methods.

So you can implement this method to both validate that the string is not too long and, if necessary, truncate it when it is too long.

Answer (score 1):

From `NSManagedObject` you can access the `NSEntityDescription` via `entity`. In there you can grab the array `properties` and a dictionary `propertiesByName`, either of which will get you to `NSPropertyDescription`s. Each property description has a property, `validationPredicates` that will return an array of `NSPredicate`s. One of those will be the condition that your string length must be at most 40.

Sadly predicates are a lot of hassle to reverse engineer — and doing so can even be impossible, given that you can create one by supplying a block. Hopefully though you'll just have an `NSComparisonPredicate` or be able to get to one by tree walking downward from an `NSCompoundPredicate` or an `NSExpression`.

From the comparison predicate you'll be able to spot from the left and right expressions that one is string length and the other is a constant value.

So, in summary:

- Core Data exposes validation criteria only via the very general means of predicates;
- you can usually, but not always, rebuild an expression (in the natural language sense rather than the `NSExpression` sense) from a predicate; and
- if you know specifically you're just looking for a length comparison somewhere then you can simplify that further into a tree walk for comparison predicates that involve the length.

It's definitely not going to be pretty because of the mismatch of the specific and the general but it is possible.